# Is there an efficient way to pass user-side JS data to backend C#, every time it changes?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a front end JS application (with visual sliders) and whenever the user updates the slider, I want to send the new information to the C# backend (ASP.NET).  From what I've found, AJAX is going to be the best way to do so.  But I don't want the backend to be constantly firing AJAX requests - only when the user makes a change.  Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: "*I don't want the backend to be constantly firing AJAX requests*" The backend can not fire Ajax requests....

Comment: I am confused, you are stating that you need to send new information to the server every time the user changes the value, but then complaining that you do not want to have a bunch of calls to the server to send this data.  Either accept that you will have to make a call for every data change or alter the mechanism that determines when new information is sent to the server.  In other words, if you do not want a request sent every time the user moves the slider, then have a "save" or "update" button on your UI for saving/updating the slider values.

Comment: Or is your real question "how do I setup change tracking in my front-end JS application"?  If so, then more information is needed on your front-end JS application, is it plain ol' JavaScript, KnockoutJS?  There are methods using JavaScript prototypes to track changes, as well as GitHub libraries to add change tracking to frameworks like KnockoutJS.  More information would be helpful in recommendations for you.  :-)

Comment: Thanks - yes, I want to update every time the user makes changes.  Other solutions I've seen have involved constant updating (instead of waiting for a user change) which I'd like to avoid.  The user end is in Knockout.  It seemed like there wasn't a good way to link Knockout to a backend, but if there are libraries I could add to get around this I will definitely look into them.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of state in your javascript, then when your event handler fires you can check to see if state changed before firing the ajax request